# Consulta SQL para definir Inicio de semana en Jueves y realizar sumar dentro de ese rango de fechas

Tags: sql, vbscript

Buen día a tod@s.

Esta es la situación..

Tengo una tabla donde se almacenan los datos de los empleados, el sueldo varia por día, necesito saber el sueldo por semana de cada empleado, definiendo el inicio de la semana el día **Jueves** y finalizando la semana el día **Miércoles** la consulta debe regresar las ultimas **13 semanas** laboradas con su total a pagar por semana.

**Ejemplo**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Aquí nos muestra las ultimas 13 semanas pero inician de Domingo a Lunes así que la suma a pagar no es correcta.*

Hasta ahora e intentado algo como esto...

Tomo la fecha actual con ***GetDate()*** y después esa fecha la busco en otra tabla donde tengo los rangos de la semanas:

***"Fecha between FechaInicio and FechaFinal"***

y me devuelve los rango de fechas a las que pertenece ese registro.

Ya con los rangos de la semana, ahora tomo todos los datos en ese rango y Sumo el total de cada dia y me regresa el total de la semana.

Hasta aquí todo bien, pero esto es solo para 1 empleado y solo es de la ultima semana. Yo necesito las ultimas **13 semanas** de cada **empleado** con su respectivo **sueldo por semana.**

Espero que me puedan apoyar, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes una tabla con el salario diario, puedes valerte de *[set DATEFIRST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)* para que las semanas vayan de jueves a miércoles.

Según la documentación:

> Establece el primer día de la semana en un número del 1 al 7.
> number | @ number_var
> Es un entero que indica el primer día de la semana. Puede ser uno de los siguientes valores.
>
> ...
>
> 4   Jueves

Esto hará que la función `datepart(week, ...)` nos devuelva números de semana que van de jueves a miércoles.

Después de eso, la solución parece bastante natural. Podrías, por ejemplo, valerte de un *pivot* para realizar una consulta que devuelva resultados de base como para la visualización que muestras.

En el ejemplo anterior, con un CTE simulo una hipotética tabla `SalarioDiario`, y obtengo la tabla de las últimas 13 semanas (OJO, si corres el ejemplo después del 24 de septiembre de 2021 ya no mostrará datos, pues el último dato queda ya después de las 13 semanas, ajusta las fechas en ese caso).

La consulta principal, calcula el número de semanas desde el salario hasta la semana actual, filtra las últimas 13 semanas (sin incluir la actual) y hace un pivote simple por empleado, mostrando la suma de los salarios en cada columna.

```
set datefirst 4;

with 
SalarioDiario as (
select *
  from (values (1, cast('20210701' as date), cast(1.00 as Money)) --jueves
             , (1, '20210702', 1) 
             , (1, '20210705', 1)
             , (1, '20210706', 1)
             , (1, '20210707', 1)
             , (1, '20210708', 2) --jueves
             , (1, '20210709', 2) 
             , (1, '20210712', 2)
             , (1, '20210713', 2)
             , (1, '20210714', 2)
             , (1, '20210715', 3) --jueves
             , (1, '20210716', 3) 
             , (1, '20210719', 3)
             , (1, '20210720', 3)
             , (1, '20210721', 3)
             , (2, '20210701', 150)
             , (2, '20210702', 150)
             , (2, '20210705', 150)
             , (2, '20210706', 150)
             , (2, '20210707', 150)
             , (2, '20210708', 150)
             , (2, '20210709', 150)
             , (2, '20210712', 150)
             , (2, '20210713', 150)
             , (2, '20210714', 150)
             , (2, '20210715', 150)
             , (2, '20210716', 150)
             , (2, '20210719', 150)
             , (2, '20210720', 150)
             , (2, '20210721', 150)
       ) q1 (idEmpleado, Fecha, Salario)
)
select idEmpleado, [13], [12], [11], [10], [9], [8], [7], [6], [5], [4], [3], [2], [1] 
  from (select   idEmpleado
               , datepart(week, getdate()) - datepart(week, fecha) semana
               , Salario
          from SalarioDiario
         where datepart(week, getdate()) - datepart(week, fecha) between 1 and 13
       ) as SourceTable
pivot (
       sum(Salario)
       for semana in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13])
      ) as PivotTable
```

Los resultados obtenidos son:

```
idEmp 13   12   11   10   9    8    7    6    5    4    3    2      1
----- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ------ ------
1     NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 5.00   10.00
2     NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 750.00 750.00

(2 rows affected)


Completion time: 2021-07-21T12:23:41.2224831-06:00
```